# Regex to validate both protocol and subdomain in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate, url-validation

I am trying to validate a URL with jQuery validator, but the regex I'm using is falsely validating a domain with subdomain (e.g.: `subdomain.domain`) without a TLD as true.

I have this, which validates a subdomain:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domainChk", function (value, element, params) {
    if (this.optional(element)) return true;
    var regExp = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$");
    return regExp.test(value);
}, "Valid hostname required for player code");
```

It also isn't validating the TLD correctly. So, I could enter `subdomain.domain.aaa123` and it validates. It also validates fewer than a 2 character TLD as well.

**This only needs to validate for US viewers (so .ca for Canada or the like is not necessary to validate for)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Basically you can create an A element and access parts of the URL:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

Here's more documentation about the widely supported HTMLAnchorElement object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

Comment: I've updated my post with more detail on the code I'm using. I just need a way at this point to validate the protocol as well, and make sure that the TLD is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do so work if you want restrict the TLD. But here is a starting place:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/([0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z]\.)+(<TLD list>)/g
```